# Show that a convolution of two functions solves an ODE

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, convolution

Given a function $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, meaning $f$ is continuous with compact support in $\mathbb{R}$, and function $\Phi(x) = \frac12|x|$, show that the convolution $u=f \ast \Phi$ is well defined and a solution to $$u^{\prime\prime}=f(x) \ \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$$
I really don´t know how to tackle this problem. In our lecture we went over a proposition that defines the derivative of a convolution, but since $\Phi$ is not continuously differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$ and f is not explicitly given I don´t know how to use it here. Help would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You have $\Phi''(x)=\delta_0(x)$, and the Dirac-delta is the convolutional identity...

Comment: Could you explain why $\Phi^{\prime\prime}(x) = \delta_0(x)$ or link me to a proof somewhere please? I know that $ \frac{d}{dx} |x| = sign(x)$ but I don´t see how the derivative of $sign(x)$ is the Dirac-delta. In our lecture we didn´t cover the Dirac delta being the convolutional identity but I can see that by just plugging it in.

Comment: $\Phi'(x)$ is piecewise constant with a jump of size $1$ at the origin, the derivative of such a jump is the delta-distribution. If you want to do this precisely you have to write down the convolution integrals and apply partial integration to the appropriate segments of the integration domain.